# The network is not present or not started. Check that you are connected to the network, and then try again

Tags: sharepoint-server, document

I can confirm that the network is connected. Attempted to open a powerpoint file on sharepoint but received error in title. A few user has complained of same issue as well, and can confirm it is not a network issue. Any suggestions to what the cause may be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure workstation service is set to automatic & its started or if it doesn't resolve give a try to reset TCP/IP stack.

Here are some articles for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc978892(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://www.troublefixers.com/network-is-not-present-or-not-started-error-while-trying-to-connect-to-any-network-folder/

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to restart the office application (word in my case) if the workstation service runs and the TCP/IP stack is OK.